# HP EliteBook 845 G8 Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS Wifi not detected

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, hp

I have an HP EliteBook 845 G8 laptop and recently installed Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS on it (Windows was previously installed). After installing Ubuntu I can connect to the Internet via Ethernet without any problem, but the laptop doesn't detect Wifi at all (no Wifi tab in Settings).

I can't add Additional Drivers even when I'm connected to the Internet:

[Software & Updates: Additional Drivers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io8Ic.png)

[Software & Updates: Ubuntu Software - Downloadable from the Internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5I0Y5.png)

More info (in the link the result of the terminal command):

[dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HPqRp.png)

ii  linux-modules-extra-5.13.0-28-generic 5.13.0-28.31~20.04.1                        amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.13.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP

[lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLj21.png)

01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Device [17cb:1103] (rev 01)
Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e0bb]

02:00.0 USB controller [0c03]: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1912:0015] (rev 02)
Subsystem: Renesas Technology Corp. uPD720202 USB 3.0 Host Controller [1912:0015]
Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd

0: hci0: Bluetooth

```
Soft blocked: no

Hard blocked: no
```

[sudo lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jG7L7.png)

*-network UNCLAIMED

```
   description: Network controller

   product: Qualcomm

   vendor: Qualcomm

   physical id: 0

   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0

   version: 01

   width: 64 bits

   clock: 33MHz

   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list

   configuration: latency=0

   resources: memory:fb000000-fb1fffff
```

*-network

```
   description: Ethernet interface

   physical id: 2

   bus info: usb@6:1

   logical name: enxf8e43ba0edfe

   serial: f8:e4:3b:a0:ed:fe

   size: 1Gbit/s

   capacity: 1Gbit/s

   capabilities: ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=ax88179_178a driverversion=5.13.0-28-generic duplex=full ip=192.168.100.93 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
```

[sudo dmidecode -s bios-version; sudo dmidecode -s bios-release-date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJv54.png)

T82 Ver. 01.06.03

09/17/2021

I'm a newbie when it comes to using Ubuntu, but if you need any additional information to solve this problem I'll be glad to post it:)

Comment: You could try Ubuntu 21.10 as it has better support for more recent hardware. Or something like Manjaro.

Comment: The first 2 screen shots add noting to the question and are just a pain to look at. The 3 rd one is text and text needs to be in the question not as a pic. I did not look at the links past the 3 rd one.